# SQL date comparison issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

How is it possible that the 1st query returns records for today and yesterday, but the 2nd one returns only for yesterday?

1st

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  table
WHERE
  DateTimeOfInsert >= '20160714'
```

2nd

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  table
WHERE
    DateTimeOfInsert >= '20160714' 
  AND 
    DateTimeOfInsert <= '20160715'
```

I can't use `BETWEEN` as it is allowed to provide only one of `start` / `end` dates.

Comment: you need to change DateTimeOfInsert <= '20160715' to DateTimeOfInsert < '20160716'

Comment: @JatinPatel But why? `<=` should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: when you provide only date without time part it will only matches to the midnight of the day. It will ignore the date if it has time after midnight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the Time. You are technically searching for 2016-07-14 00:00:00 to 2016-07-15 00:00:00, which only consists 2016-07-14 data.

If you need to find on both 2 days, then:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  table
WHERE
    DateTimeOfInsert >= '2016-07-14 00:00:00' 
  AND 
    DateTimeOfInsert <= '2016-07-15 23:59:59'
```

or simply use this for the second condition

```
DateTimeOfInsert <= '20160716'
```

which implies between 2016-07-14 00:00:00 to 2016-07-16 00:00:00

Comment: Just realized. Used `CAST(DateTimeOfInsert AS DATE)`. Thanks though.

Comment: instead of casting the column to date, better you adjust your parameter or fixed values to include time up to the end of day. It will be better at performance point

Comment: @JatinPatel I'm listening. `CAST` is worse in terms of performance?

Comment: not always, but when you apply it to a table column which is used in condition, it may not be able to do effective use of the index on the column.

Comment: @JatinPatel - `CAST` to `date` is [sargable](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea)

Comment: The time resolution is usually finer than seconds, so you should really filter for `DateTimeOfInsert >= '2016-07-14 00:00:00' AND DateTimeOfInsert < '2016-07-16 00:00:00'`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `BETWEEN` [statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)?

Your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE DateTimeOfInsert >= '2016-07-14 00:00:00' 
AND DateTimeOfInsert < '2016-07-16  00:00:00'
```

Comment: Please read my question. I did explain why I can't use `BETWEEN`.

Comment: So, you want to ignore everything that happens *during* the last second before midnight? (non-zero milliseconds value). This is why most people advise against using `BETWEEN` and using `<` rather than `<=`. The *exclusive* end point tends to be easy to compute and doesn't rely on the precision of the data type being used.

Comment: `DateTimeOfInsert > '2016-07-14 00:00:00'` (exclusive) should be `DateTimeOfInsert >= '2016-07-14 00:00:00'` (inclusive), the end condition is correct though.